# During a Google+ Instant Upload, is it all or nothing?

Tags: google-plus, instant-upload

I'm in the middle of an "Upload All" but I don't see anything online yet? Is it an all or nothing upload? My upload keeps getting stuck on the next to last item. It would be nice if I could see the first 356 of 358 items while the last 2 items are uploaded (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should show your pictures as they are added (AKA not all-or-nothing). I'd try rebooting your device, also check if maybe your battery level is low (under I think 20% it doesn't upload, similar to dropbox)